# Wordpress Custom Post Type rewrite_tag not replaced in editor

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

Hey this one is killing me!

I have a custom post type called 'features'.

The archive page for it is currently visible via: 
**mysite.com/features/**

and currently the single feature is at: 
**mysite.com/features/single-post/**

however i would like the single feature to be available at:
**mysite.com/feautres/23423/single-post/**

ie the $post->ID being added to the url.

This is working on the front end and rewriting correctly however in the wordpress admin its showing the links as: 
**mysite.com/feautres/%cpt_id%/single-post/**

This is what the code I have so far;

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'cpt_url', 1, 3);
function cpt_url($post_link, $id = 0, $leavename) {

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $post = &get_post($id);
    if ( is_wp_error( $post ) )
        return $post;
    $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct('features');
    $newlink = str_replace("%postid%", $post->ID, $newlink);
    $newlink = home_url(user_trailingslashit($newlink));

    return $newlink.$post->post_name.'/';    

}

add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrites');
function sumo_add_custom_rewrites(){

    global $wp_rewrite;

    //rewrites for feature
    $queryarg = 'post_type=features&p=';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%postid%', '([^/]+)', $queryarg);
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('features', '/features/%postid%', false);

}
```

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Manged to solve it thankfully!

Ok so the add_filter('post_type_link', 'cpt_url', 1, 3); was correct but i had it getting added on the front-end (i know)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was I was calling the post_type_link filter in the wrong place

After adding it to the int hook it all works